# Angular always refreshing page after put something, even true value, in the URL

Tags: angular, url, routes

My problem is about routing.

Always when I put something in URL, Angular is refreshing my page. Routing works properly with buttons and navigations routerLinks. For some cases using useHash helps but not for everything, for example oAuth, when Api is redirecting to my page, when I want to get data from URL, even with {useHash: true} app won't work properly. For 2 days I'm searching solutions for that problem and I decided to create new topic. Thank you! :)

Comment: your API  sould return values, not redirect to page. A redirect to page **always** refresh the page. Some if you use a link and not a routerLink

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the https://stackoverflow.com/tour (and earn a badge while you are at it) / Also read our https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask page and edit your question to improve it. Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community. For starters, please include a minimal reproducible example to your question. Otherwise, it might take a lot more time and a heap of guessing to figure exactly where the issue lies.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement your own `RouteReuseStrategy` to provides a way to customize when activated routes get reused or completely reload, Angular by default use `BaseRouteReuseStrategy` that this base route reuse strategy only reuses routes when the matched router configs are identical. This prevents components from being destroyed and recreated when just the **fragment** or **query parameters** change (that is, the existing component is reused).